# WPF Textsearch item in Listbox created in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I would like to search items in my ListBox by typing. I found it can be done by TextSearch Property.

ListBox XAML:

```
     <ListBox x:Name="SzablonyBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
             Background="{x:Null}" TextSearch.TextPath="Text" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewKeyDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding nazwa}" FontWeight="Bold"
                               FontSize="15" Height="35"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               TextAlignment="Justify"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

How to set `TextSearch.TextPath="Text"` to look after ListBox items (TextBlock text) ?

Comment: Your ListBox is bound to to a collection right (ItemsSource)? This collection has objects with the property nazwa right? Then TextSearch.TextPath="nazwa". Check: https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/textsearch/

Comment: It works. Thanks